Prononciation de « Brot »
Le nom propre « Brot » se trouve dans « miroir Brot » ; quelle est la prononciation de ce mot ? Le t se prononce dans « Lot » et le o est mi-ouvert ; qu'en est-il dans le cas de « Brot » ? Est-ce un homophone de « broc » ?

https://www.academie-francaise.fr/henri-m-france

@None Il n'est pas question de règle ; est-ce que « Lot » est prononcé selon une règle ? Non, c'est comme ça,  c'est tout. On ne donne pas la prononciation de ce nom propre sur la toile.

Il n' a pas de règle pour les noms propres. Donc ça dépend des gens et des régions (on prononce plus facilement les finales dans le midi de la France). Opinion-based.

@None Je demande celle de « Brot » dans « miroir Brot » ; ça ne dépend que de Brot, celui qui fait les miroirs, pas des gens et des régions.

Si « ça ne dépend que de Brot » pour savoir comment lui,  François Brot, le prononçait (il est mort depuis longtemps!! d'où l'imparfait) il faut lui demander. Tu peux aussi téléphoner à la Maison Brot. Moi je dis [bro] mais je pense qu'il y aura bien quelqu'un pour dire autrement.

@None Non, il ne faut pas demander au gens (10 courriels par jour avec « comment prononce-t-on votre nom ? » Non-sens) ; pour « Weil » (Simone Weil) j'ai une référence (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu73q_eEICE) ; Simone Weil, elle, est morte, la maison Brot existe toujours https://www.miroirbrot.fr/. Il doit bien y avoir une référence quelque part, ou quelqu'un qui sait.

I’m voting to close this question because asking how a specific surname is pronounced in one specific case, and it is not about the French Language.

Voilà le numéro: Tél. : 01 60 83 61 67 https://www.miroirbrot.fr/

@Lambie Je n'ai pas à importuner ces gens-là avec des questions de langue, et je ne vais pas le faire.  S'il veulent lire « broute » quand il lisent Beckett ou autre chose, eh bien qu'ils le fassent !

Ha ha. Importuné? Ils vont dire le nom et tu peux raccrocher. Seul les nommants/nommés savent comment prononcer les noms qu'ils ont donné à ceci ou cela.

Le T final des noms communs français en -ot est le plus souvent muet (avec au moins une exception: dot) mais la prononciation des noms propres est libre.
Il y a certainement des Brot qui prononcent le T et d'autres pas, c'est leur choix et tout le monde les comprend quel qu'il soit. Ce choix peut être régional et on trouve des Brot dans différentes régions. J'imagine par exemple qu'en Alsace, on aurait tendance à le prononcer /bʁo:t/.
Si tu veux savoir comment ceux qui gèrent Miroir Brot à Paris le prononcent, téléphone-leur ! (01 60 83 61 67). Ils se présenteront peut-être directement sans même que tu aies besoin de leur demander :-)
Est-ce un homophone de « broc » ?
Excellent exemple : broc se prononce le plus souvent /bʁo/ quand il s'agit d'une carafe mais se prononce /bʁɔk/ dans l'expression de bric et de broc ainsi que dans les deux localités françaises nommées Le Broc (Puy-de-Dôme et Alpes-Maritimes).

C'est le « Brot » dans  « miroir Brot » dont il est question, c'est tout ; le reste n'est que des compléments. Il vaut mieux, lorsqu'on parlera de ces fameux miroirs, qu'on connaisse la prononciation pour ce cas-là. // Il y a même une exception plus appropriée , vu la question, puisque c'est un nom propre : le département du Lot  a un nom où le t est toujours prononcé, partout ; je n'ai jamais entendu « le lo ».

J'aurais pu ajouté, mais je n'ai pas cru nécessaire le faire, qu'on trouve « miroir Brot » dans Malloy, de Samuel Beckett.

Ce n'est pas parce qu'une prononciation est très répandue que c'est la prononciation correcte. Par exemple le patronyme du pilote français Alain Prost est prononcé /prɔst/ par l'écrasante majorité des Français, mais la prononciation logique devrait être /pro/ comme dans Prévost par exemple. C'est comme ça qu'on prononce souvent encore Prost en Bourgogne.

Ce qui compte pour ces noms propres fameux c'est comment les personnes en question les prononcent ou comment il est d'usage de les prononcer pour les entités en question. Dans un dictionnaire de prononciation de l'anglais comme le LPD, par exemple, ces choses-là sont mentionnées (par exemple, for  « Carnegie » il y a la prononciation pour la personne  (Andrew), et celle pour le « Hall »).

@LPH On dit le Lot [lɔt], oui, ce département est en Occitanie, et il tient son nom de la rivière du même nom, qui se dit Olt [ɔlt] en occitan, ancienne graphie Oltes [ɔltes] .  La nom de famille Lot est aussi assez répandu en Occitanie, en particulier dans le Lot. Mais moi j'ai pas gagné le gros lot [lɔ] !

@None Ah oui ! Mais c'est le « lot » avec un petit l…

@LPH Pourquoi n'appelles-tu pas leur numéro ? Si tu es timide, fais appel à un(e) ami(e) !

Ce n'est pas que pour moi, c'est pour tout le monde qui lit « miroir Brot » dans Beckett et ailleurs.  Faire des contributions pour rien, passe encore, mais payer pour des appels téléphoniques  gratis pro deo c'est une autre histoire.

Appelle et apporte une réponse à ta propre question. Personnellement, je me fiche de savoir comment François Brot le prononçait au XIXe siècle et comment ceux qui gèrent la marque aujourd'hui le font; Ca ne m'empêcherait pas du tout de lire Malloy le cas échéant. Sinon, tu payes pour un appel sur une ligne fixe ?? Tu devrais changer de fournisseur. C'est normalement inclus dans tous les forfaits.

Lire Molloy, je veux dire.
